# Adding confidence intervals to back-transformed regression plots of interactions

Tags: r, ggplot2, lme4, confidence-interval, interaction

I have a mixed effects model which (a) has a log-link and (b) includes a continuous by continuous interaction. I want to plot the interaction effects, back-transformed. I have managed to do this by plotting three lines of the Y~X1 relationship, one at each of: the mean X2 -1SD, mean X2, and mean X2 + 1SD. However, I really need to add confidence intervals to the plot. geom_ribbon doesn't work properly. Can anyone help? Any suggestions not using ggplot2 also welcome. Here is the code for the plots without confidence intervals:

```
#the data

mydata<-structure(list(Week = c(3L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), X2 = c(20.8, 21.4, 22.2, 21.9, 21, 21.8, 
16.6, 15.6, 21.9, 19.8, 17.5, 12.5, 20.1, 20.5, 21.7, 22.3), 
    X1 = c(78L, 90L, 81L, 44L, 9L, 35L, 99L, 17L, 1L, 7L, 23L, 
    14L, 9L, 77L, 84L, 1L), Y = c(14.97469781, 19.88267242, 15.59780954, 
    9.633809968, 15.12038794, 10.43636012, 10.7436911, 16.71840387, 
    12.43274774, 10.90741585, 8.79514591, 14.1932374, 8.776376951, 
    9.995133069, 12.38314719, 9.611533444)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L))

attach(mydata)

#the model

Fmim<-glmer(Y~X1*X2+(1|Week),data=mydata,family=Gamma(link='log'))

E<-fixef(Fmim)

#set xf = to the mean X2 -1SD
xf=17.016

##then create a dummy variable
dummyx0<-seq(length=100,from=min(X1),to=max(X1))

##then create the y values from these dummy x values produced above
##because I logged the data, I have to do exponentiate the model to back-transform

y1x0<-(exp(E[1]+((E[3])*xf)+((E[2])*dummyx0)+((E[4])*xf*dummyx0)))



#set xf = to the mean X2
xf=19.85

#create the new y variable 

y2x0<-(exp(E[1]+((E[3])*xf)+((E[2])*dummyx0)+((E[4])*xf*dummyx0)))



#set xf = to the mean X2 + 1sD
xf=25.134


#create the new y variable

y3x0<-(exp(E[1]+((E[3])*xf)+((E[2])*dummyx0)+((E[4])*xf*dummyx0)))



plotdata1<-data.frame(x=dummyx0,y=y1x0)
plotdata2<-data.frame(x=dummyx0,y=y2x0)
plotdata3<-data.frame(x=dummyx0,y=y3x0)


ggplot(plotdata1)+
  geom_point(data = mydata, aes(x=X1, y=Y), size = 3.5, shape=1)+
  geom_line(data = plotdata1, aes(y=y1x0, x=dummyx0), size=1)+
  geom_line(data = plotdata2, aes(y=y2x0, x=dummyx0), size=1)+
  geom_line(data = plotdata3, aes(y=y3x0, x=dummyx0), size=1)+
  scale_colour_manual("",values="blue")+
  scale_fill_manual("",values="grey12")+
  labs(x=bquote("X1"), y = "Y") + 
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))+
  theme(legend.position ="none") +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size=15), # for axix
        title = element_text(size=10),axis.text = element_text(size=15),
        axis.title.x = element_text(vjust = 0),
        axis.title.y = element_text(vjust = 2, hjust=0.5), 
        legend.title = element_text(vjust = 0.5))
```

Comment: `Error: object 'dummy2x0' not found`, and the same for the next one, `dummy3x0`.

Comment: Apologies @RuiBarradas - I thought that I had edited that out. Now the code should work. Any ideas?